# Objective function does not converge using Gekko

Tags: python, gekko

I tried running this code but the objective function diverges even when I raise the maximum of iterations (raised it to 2000 and still didn't find a solution).

Any help is welcome.

`The code:`

```py
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from gekko import GEKKO

m = GEKKO()

plt.rcParams['font.size'] = 15

# Parameters
nu_float = 0.5
beta_E_float = 10.0
tau_E_float=0.05
delta_E_float=0.03
beta_F_float=0.01
s_h_float = 0.9951
delta_F_float = 0.04
eta_float = 0.95
delta_float = 1.25
F_star = 5106.0
b_float = nu_float*beta_F_float*beta_E_float/(tau_E_float+delta_E_float)#3.125
print('b='+str(b_float))
K_float = F_star/(nu_float*beta_F_float/delta_F_float-nu_float*beta_F_float/b_float)
print('K='+str(K_float))
nu=m.Param(value=nu_float)
beta_E=m.Param(value=beta_E_float)
tau_E=m.Param(value=tau_E_float)
delta_E=m.Param(value=delta_E_float)
beta_F=m.Param(value=beta_F_float)
b=m.Param(value=b_float)
s_h=m.Param(value=s_h_float)
delta_F=m.Param(value=delta_F_float)
eta=m.Param(value=eta_float)
delta=m.Param(value=delta_float)
K=m.Param(value=K_float)
T = 80
C = 1000
U_bar = 150


# Time interval
nt = 500
m.time = np.linspace(0,T,nt)
delta_t = T/nt


# Control
u = m.MV(lb=0,ub=U_bar)
u.STATUS = 1
u.DCOST = 0


# Variables
E_u = m.Var(value=K*(1-delta_F/b))
F_u = m.Var(value=F_star)
E_i = m.Var(value=0.0)
F_i = m.Var(value=0.0)
U = m.Var(value=0.0)


# Vector to extract the final value
final_array = np.zeros(nt)
final_array[-1] = 1.0
final = m.Param(value=final_array)


# Equations
m.Equation(E_u.dt()==beta_E*F_u*(1-s_h*F_i/(F_u+F_i))*(1-(E_u+E_i)/K)-(tau_E+delta_E)*E_u)
m.Equation(F_u.dt()==nu*beta_F*E_u-delta_F*F_u)
m.Equation(E_i.dt()==eta*beta_E*F_i*(1-(E_u+E_i)/K)-(tau_E+delta_E)*E_i)
m.Equation(F_i.dt()==nu*beta_F*E_i-delta*delta_F*F_i+u)
m.Equation(U.dt()==u)
m.Equation(final*U<=C)


# Objective Function
m.Obj(0.5*(final*E_u)**2+0.5*(0.5*(abs(K*(1-delta*delta_F/(b*eta))-final*E_i)+K*(1-delta*delta_F/(b*eta))-final*E_i))**2+0.5*(final*F_u)**2+0.5*(0.5*(abs(K*(nu*beta_F/(delta*delta_F)-nu*beta_F/(b*eta))-final*F_i)+K*(nu*beta_F/(delta*delta_F)-nu*beta_F/(b*eta))-final*F_i))**2)


# Resolution
m.options.IMODE = 6
m.options.NODES = 4
m.options.MV_TYPE = 1
m.options.SOLVER = 3
print('beginning of computations')
m.solve()
print('end of computations')


# Print results
E_u_array=np.transpose(np.matrix(E_u))
F_u_array=np.transpose(np.matrix(F_u))
E_i_array=np.transpose(np.matrix(E_i))
F_i_array=np.transpose(np.matrix(F_i))
u_array=np.transpose(np.matrix(u))
U_array=np.transpose(np.matrix(U))
t_array = np.arange(nt)*T/nt
E_u_T = float(final_array*E_u_array)
F_u_T = float(final_array*F_u_array)
E_i_T = float(final_array*E_i_array)
F_i_T = float(final_array*F_i_array)
print(r'$E_u(T):$ ' + str(E_u_T))
print(r'$F_u(T):$ ' + str(F_u_T))
print(r'$E_i(T):$ ' + str(E_i_T))
print(r'$F_i(T):$ ' + str(F_i_T))
```

The error

```
 
 An error occured.
 The error code is           -1
 
 
 ---------------------------------------------------
 Solver         :  IPOPT (v3.12)
 Solution time  :    124.735700000005      sec
 Objective      :    11931117306673.5
 Unsuccessful with error code            0
 ---------------------------------------------------
 
 Creating file: infeasibilities.txt
 Use command apm_get(server,app,'infeasibilities.txt') to retrieve file
 @error: Solution Not Found
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dave\tipe 2k22.py", line 86, in <module>
    m.solve()
  File "c:\users\dave\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\gekko\gekko.py", line 2185, in solve
    raise Exception(response)
Exception:  @error: Solution Not Found
```

Answer (score 0):

The `abs()` functions in the objective function are not differentiable at `x=0`. Try switching to `m.abs3()` for a binary variable switch that is continuously differentiable.

```py
# Objective Function
m.Minimize(0.5*(final*E_u)**2\
      +0.5*(0.5*(m.abs3(K*(1-delta*delta_F/(b*eta))-final*E_i)\
      +K*(1-delta*delta_F/(b*eta))-final*E_i))**2+0.5*(final*F_u)**2\
      +0.5*(0.5*(m.abs3(K*(nu*beta_F/(delta*delta_F)\
      -nu*beta_F/(b*eta))-final*F_i)+K*(nu*beta_F/(delta*delta_F)\
      -nu*beta_F/(b*eta))-final*F_i))**2)
```

You'll also need to switch to the solver `APOPT` to calculate the Mixed Integer Nonlinear Programming (MINLP) solution with `m.options.SOLVER=1`. If you leave out the `m.options.SOLVER` line then Gekko automatically selects it when the `m.abs3()` function is used. You can override it with another solver selection, if desired, but it won't necessarily return an integer solution. More information on the binary form of the `abs()` function is in the [Optimization online course (Logical Conditions in Optimization)](https://apmonitor.com/me575/index.php/Main/LogicalConditions).

```py
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from gekko import GEKKO

m = GEKKO()

plt.rcParams['font.size'] = 15

# Parameters
nu_float = 0.5
beta_E_float = 10.0
tau_E_float=0.05
delta_E_float=0.03
beta_F_float=0.01
s_h_float = 0.9951
delta_F_float = 0.04
eta_float = 0.95
delta_float = 1.25
F_star = 5106.0
b_float = nu_float*beta_F_float*beta_E_float/(tau_E_float+delta_E_float)#3.125
print('b='+str(b_float))
K_float = F_star/(nu_float*beta_F_float/delta_F_float-nu_float*beta_F_float/b_float)
print('K='+str(K_float))
nu=m.Param(value=nu_float)
beta_E=m.Param(value=beta_E_float)
tau_E=m.Param(value=tau_E_float)
delta_E=m.Param(value=delta_E_float)
beta_F=m.Param(value=beta_F_float)
b=m.Param(value=b_float)
s_h=m.Param(value=s_h_float)
delta_F=m.Param(value=delta_F_float)
eta=m.Param(value=eta_float)
delta=m.Param(value=delta_float)
K=m.Param(value=K_float)
T = 80
C = 1000
U_bar = 150

# Time interval
nt = 100
m.time = np.linspace(0,T,nt)
delta_t = T/nt

# Control
u = m.MV(lb=0,ub=U_bar)
u.STATUS = 1
u.DCOST = 0

# Variables
E_u = m.Var(value=K*(1-delta_F/b))
F_u = m.Var(value=F_star)
E_i = m.Var(value=0.0)
F_i = m.Var(value=0.0)
U = m.Var(value=0.0)

# Vector to extract the final value
final_array = np.zeros(nt)
final_array[-1] = 1.0
final = m.Param(value=final_array)

# Equations
m.Equation(E_u.dt()==beta_E*F_u*(1-s_h*F_i/(F_u+F_i))\
                     *(1-(E_u+E_i)/K)-(tau_E+delta_E)*E_u)
m.Equation(F_u.dt()==nu*beta_F*E_u-delta_F*F_u)
m.Equation(E_i.dt()==eta*beta_E*F_i*(1-(E_u+E_i)/K)\
                     -(tau_E+delta_E)*E_i)
m.Equation(F_i.dt()==nu*beta_F*E_i-delta*delta_F*F_i+u)
m.Equation(U.dt()==u)

m.Equation(final*U<=C)

# Objective Function
m.Minimize(0.5*(final*E_u)**2\
      +0.5*(0.5*(m.abs3(K*(1-delta*delta_F/(b*eta))-final*E_i)\
      +K*(1-delta*delta_F/(b*eta))-final*E_i))**2+0.5*(final*F_u)**2\
      +0.5*(0.5*(m.abs3(K*(nu*beta_F/(delta*delta_F)\
      -nu*beta_F/(b*eta))-final*F_i)+K*(nu*beta_F/(delta*delta_F)\
      -nu*beta_F/(b*eta))-final*F_i))**2)

# Resolution
m.options.IMODE = 6
m.options.NODES = 3
m.options.MV_TYPE = 1
m.options.SOLVER = 1
print('beginning of computations')
m.solve()
print('end of computations')

# Print results
E_u_array=np.transpose(np.matrix(E_u))
F_u_array=np.transpose(np.matrix(F_u))
E_i_array=np.transpose(np.matrix(E_i))
F_i_array=np.transpose(np.matrix(F_i))
u_array=np.transpose(np.matrix(u))
U_array=np.transpose(np.matrix(U))
t_array = np.arange(nt)*T/nt
E_u_T = float(final_array*E_u_array)
F_u_T = float(final_array*F_u_array)
E_i_T = float(final_array*E_i_array)
F_i_T = float(final_array*F_i_array)
print(r'$E_u(T):$ ' + str(E_u_T))
print(r'$F_u(T):$ ' + str(F_u_T))
print(r'$E_i(T):$ ' + str(E_i_T))
print(r'$F_i(T):$ ' + str(F_i_T))
```

This produces a successful solution:

```
 --------- APM Model Size ------------
 Each time step contains
   Objects      :            0
   Constants    :            0
   Variables    :           27
   Intermediates:            0
   Connections  :            0
   Equations    :           13
   Residuals    :           13
 
 Number of state variables:           4356
 Number of total equations: -         3861
 Number of slack variables: -          990
 ---------------------------------------
 Degrees of freedom       :           -495
 
 * Warning: DOF <= 0
 ----------------------------------------------
 Dynamic Control with APOPT Solver
 ----------------------------------------------
Iter:     1 I:  0 Tm:      5.72 NLPi:    7 Dpth:    0 Lvs:    0 Obj:  1.61E+11 Gap:  0.00E+00
 Successful solution
 
 ---------------------------------------------------
 Solver         :  APOPT (v1.0)
 Solution time  :    5.74739999999292      sec
 Objective      :    160555572371.779     
 Successful solution
 ---------------------------------------------------
 
end of computations
$E_u(T):$ 40801.053817
$F_u(T):$ 5092.8119666
$E_i(T):$ 39.66478887
$F_i(T):$ 63.713604115
```